# Adding a Custom ID with Python & Regex

Tags: python, regex, text, markdown

I have a document in markdown that I want to add a custom id for each city entry. The basic layout of the document is as follows:

```
#Country

## StateA

### CityA
#### Population
#### Government
#### History

### CityB
#### Population
#### Government
#### History

## StateB

### CityA
#### Population
#### Government
#### History

### CityB
#### Population
#### Government
#### History
```

For each city I would like to add a customized ID with a counter. For example the IDs would look like:

```
#USA

## FL

### US_FL_00001
### US_FL_00002
### US_FL_00003

## GA

### US_GA_00001
### US_GA_00002
### US_GA_00003
```

I know its relatively simple to use regex to select cities using re.findall() and re.sub() for the '###' headers but how can I pull in the state and a successive counter for the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there might be a difference in your sample input and sample output, but I have based my answer on your sample outout and you can tweak it to suit your needs.

The idea is to read inthe input file and line by line test to see if the line represent a Country, a State or a City. These it then stores until it reaches the rows beginning with '####' Then it outputs the results with the counter to a new file.

```py
import re

with open('input.md', 'r') as f:
    # read in the original file
    text = f.readlines()

# open the output file and loop through the original data
with open('output.md', 'w') as o:
    country_counter = counter = 0
    for line in text:
        # get the country
        m = re.match(r'^#([A-Za-z]+)', line)
        if m:
            country = m.group(1)
            # this checks to see if it is the first country
            # in the file. If so then we don't want the leading
            # newline characters
            if country_counter == 0:
                o.write(f'#{country}')
            else:
                o.write(f'\n\n#{country}')
            country_counter += 1

        # get the state
        m = re.match(r'^##\s([A-Za-z]+)', line)
        if m:
            state = m.group(1)
            # reset the counter
            counter = 0
            o.write(f'\n\n## {state}\n')

        # get the city
        m = re.match(r'^###\s([A-Za-z]+)', line)
        if m:
            # increase the counter and output the results
            # the counter is padded to 5 digits.
            counter += 1
            o.write(f'\n### {city}_{state}_{counter:05}')
```

Comment: when I tried running the code it said that on line 38 NameError: name 'counter' is not defined. Also NameError: name 'city' is not defined

Comment: @mhshaaban I edited the script by changing line 9 to `country_counter = counter = 0`. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: By the way, the provided script doesn't do any error checking and may fail on bad input For example, if a city was listed before any state, you would get an error that `state` is not defined. However, so long as the input is in the proper format, I expect the script to work as-is.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer the script is based on the examples given. Deviations from that will require tweaks to the script (as you have found). @Waylan thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thank fixed the counter issue! Thank you! If I wanted to keep the other text like `#### Population #### Government #### History` should I follow the same pattern? or would there be a more elegant solution?